# FutureAccessList unable to get an item

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app

I've an issue with the FutureAccessList (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207457). My app allows you to choose folders, I use StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add to add the corresponding folder to the list and I save the token.

```
        picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
        result = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
        if (result != null)
        {
            string token = Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(result);
            // save the token
        }
```

Everything was working fine but recently my phone (I don't know if it's linked to this issue) had a firmware update and since then when I try to call Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFolderAsync I get a FileNotFoundException, the error is irrelevant because the folder does exist and the token is the same I ask for !

I tried to investigate this issue and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. The screenshot below shows how I try to get the corresponding folder from the FutureAccessList, this screenshot also shows that the token is present in the FutureAccessList.

[Screenshot: GetFolderAsync from FutureAccessList and then the FileNotFoundException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STo9L.png)

Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: What's the result of  `StorageItemAccessList.CheckAccess`  to your folder?

Comment: @Sunteen The CheckAccess returned false, after picking the same folder it worked again but I shouldn't ask for a new token it should stay the same over the time until I uninstall the app.

Comment: So this is because you update the app. Before you update it always work.